# Admissible relations for the quiver of the preprojective algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic 0.
Let $Q_n$ be the quiver of the preprojective algebra of Dynkin type $A_n$.
So from each point $i$ to its neighbor $i+1$ there is an arrow $a_i$ and an arrow back from $i+1$ to $i$ called $a_i^{*}$. Define $p:=\sum\limits_{i}^{}{a_i a_i^{*}}$.

Then $A_n:=kQ_n/<p>$ is the preprojective algebra of Dynkin type $A_n$.

For $n=3$ the algebra is 10-dimensional and selfinjective.

Now I noted that for $n=3$, we can alaso look at the algebra $k Q_3 /<p^2>$, which is a 68-dimensional algebra that is also selfinjective. (this also works for $n=2$ but here the quiver is rather simple).

Now $kQ_4/<p^2>$ seems to be infinite dimensional. (Bonus question: Is there an easy way to see that $kQ_3/<p^2>$ is finite dimensional while $kQ_4/<p^2>$ is infinite dimensional by hand? I just did it with a computer using QPA).

> Question: Is the finite dimensional selfinjective algebra $k Q_3 /<p^2>$ just a coincidence or is there a similar construction for higher $n$ giving a finite dimensional selfinjective algebra? Can we modify the definition of $p$ to get "preprojective algebras" where the relations have summands of length 4 (instead of 2)?